# cv2.imread() vs plt.imread()

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I need some clarification on the way we read image files using cv2 vs matplotlib.

I have a image mask file on my storage, which is 512 x 512 , single channel mask of something.

Here are my observations:

```
img_plt  = plt.imread('mask1.png')
img_cv2 =  cv2.imread('mask1.png')

print(np.unique(img_cv2),np.unique(img_plt))
```

> (array([  0, 255], dtype=uint8), array([0., 1.], dtype=float32))

So, we can see here:
CV2 has read the single channel image file as 0s and 255s, while matplotlib has read the same image as 0.0s and 1.0s

My question here is:

will there be any issue if we save file using matplotlib and read the same file using cv2?  how about vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two methods since both export the image as a PNG file. In fact, you can convert an image read by cv2 or plt to the other format.

You can try the following code:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


cv2_img = cv2.imread(path)
cv2plt_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) / 255
plt_img = plt.imread(path)
```

Here, cv2plt_img is equivalent to plt_img.